# What Nvidia graphics cards are compatible with an Intel DP43TF motherboard?

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, nvidia-geforce

Some people told me that only graphics cards from the Nvidia Geforce 200 series are compatible with the Intel DP43TF motherboard. Is this true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[No.](http://downloadmirror.intel.com/15994/eng/DP43TF_TechProdSpec.pdf)

Not only is it nonsense, it makes no sense. The board has a standard PCI Express x16 slot, any card that works in a x16 PCIe will work on your board.

Assuming who ever you spoke with had some clue: It may be that your case/ PSU cannot handle more than what a GeForce 200 needs as far as cooling or power. That card is certainly not the only viable option though in general.